# Script that writes several scripts in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a script which is something like:

```
for k in {1..100..1}
do
cat << EOF > script${k}.sh

  do some things

  cat << EOF > somefile
  text
  EOF

  do some things


EOF
done
```

So, briefly put, I want 100 scripts that looks like:

```
do some things

  cat << EOF > somefile
  text
  EOF

  do some things
```

The problem is that when I run this, Bash associates the first EOF with the third one and stops writing and it starts trying to run the next commands.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I corrected a typo pointed out by Aaron below. Also, I will expand a bit my original question. Following Aaron's indication, I used END for the first and last EOF. It works fine, but I still have some trouble. Being more specific, my code looks like this:

```
for k in {1..100..1}
do
cat << END > script${k}.sh

  mkdir folder${k}
  cd folder${k}

  cat << EOF > somefile
  text
  EOF

  for j in {1..80..1}
    cat << EOF > program${j}
       text
    EOF
```

execute some stuff

```
END
done
```

I guess you see the trouble. Now the code works almost fine. The problem is with the variables. The ${k} that are between the ENDs, in the `script${k}` are not corrected substituted by the corresponding number!

Thanks for all the help :-)

Comment: You can't indent EOF, it won't be recognised.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't indent it. I just wrote it that way here in the post so you can read it more clearly

Answer (score 2):

`EOF` can be any token that will be found at the end of the heredoc, so you can use another one on the outer heredoc :

```
for k in {1..100..1}
do
cat << END > script${1}.sh
do some things

cat << EOF > somefile
text
EOF

do some things

END
done
```

A few additional notes :

- you're not using `$k`, so you're basically overwriting the same file 100 times. Did you meant `script${k}.sh` rather than `script${1}.sh` ?
- creating 100 versions of the same script seems useless, even if the script's behaviour depends on its name. Couldn't you instead pass parameters to an unique script?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I meant ${k}, of course, that was a typo. I 'll correct it now, thanks. Also, each script is of course different. I just didn't write the details of my particular code, since they didn't seem relevant

Comment: Even if they're different, you're adding an indirection that seems useless to me. Instead of generating the scripts and then executing the one you need, you could instead pass as an argument the "one you need" to an unique script that would behave as the script you need.

Comment: Aaron, I don't want to execute only one of them. I need to run them all

Comment: Well in that case it makes even less sense to create multiple scripts. I'm on mobile right now but I'll give you a script that hopefully answers your needs in 15min

Comment: Thank you so much, Aaron! I have to leave now, I'll read your message later in the nigth

Comment: [Here's](http://ideone.com/vPc7W3) how I've translated the code you've posted in your last edit. Note that it raises errors on ideone because we don't have the permission to create files.

Comment: @Aaron You can `cd $(mktemp -t -d)` at the beginning of the script and then you do have permission to create files.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the tip, I've been able to edit my code and include a directory listing to show its result.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It still wouldn't be enough for me, my code is a bit more complicated. My bad, I should have been more specific. Anyway, I've been able to solve my problem by using the sed command in a for loop and editing a template. Thanks!